# Менять text на значение переменной Unity

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-ui

Есть text на Canvas (цифра 0).
Нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку число увеличивалось на 1.
Насколько я понимаю, нужно привязать текст к переменной, но как это сделать?
И как привязать скрипт к кнопке?

Comment: Вопрос решен с описанием ниже ?

Answer (score 0):

**Порядок:**

На Canvas у нас компоненты Техt и Button

Создадим C# Script с именем ButtonClick

На Text вешаем наш скрипт ButtonClick

Выделяем Button, ищем OnClick и нажимаем на плюс

Перетягиваем туда Text со скриптом

Чуть правее в функциях ищем наш скрипт ButtonClick и выбираем функцию ChangeText()

Кликаем на кнопке - видим увеличение счетчика

Скрипт редактируемого текста можно оставить на тексте.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class ButtonClick : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    private Text textToEdit;

    private int total = 0;


    void Start()
    {
        textToEdit = GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    public void ChangeText()
    {
        total += 1;
        textToEdit.text = total.ToString();       
    }
}
```